# Static files version folders not found hence design collapsed and getting 404 for all css and js

Tags: magento2.2.2, 404, js-css

I was trying to rectify some ACL issues in my application I removed the static folder inside the pub and I run di:compile and static-content:deploy. Also, I have given 777 permission to var and generated folders, Now when I open the application in the browser no css and js is loaded, I have seen many similar issues but in my case the **css and js files are available** but the **version folder is not available** I mean if I saw the source code the URL's are like

> http://ipaddress/magento2/pub/static/version1515489121/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css

But the actual file is like

> /var/www/html/magento2/pub/**static/adminhtml**/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css

As I mentioned in the example the version folder is not showing

I don't understand how the folders are created without the version folder.

Comment: Actually the issue is while removing the static files I should have took the backup for the htaccess file, I missed it. I replace the htaccess file from the repository then its fine.

Comment: But there is no image in the pub/media file.

Answer (score 0):

try to the following:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

then

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

then

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

then

```
sudo chmod 777 -R var
```

and check the following apache2 configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

if you find `AllowOverride None`

Change it to `AllowOverride All`

Regards,

Comment: I tried your solution and @qazqaz999 both of them bring back the magento placeholder image instead of broken image but not the original one.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you had "Sign Static Files" enabled (found in Magento admin > Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Static Files Settings).

This is enabled so that the browser can detect when a newer version of a static file (CSS/JS/HTML) is available for use. This is enabled preferably when your site is subject already for go-live.

When you're in production mode (you can check this through php bin/magento deploy:mode:show) and this is enabled, you **can't** afford to lose the .htaccess file inside the /pub/static folder. The .htaccess file routes the request for the static files' towards /pub/static.php. And this file will load the static files.

Comment: I tried your solution and @Mohamed Elkashef both of them bring back the magento placeholder image instead of broken image but not the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution if showing version name in css/js path

run this query in mysql

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) 
VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

after that clear the config cache

```
 bin/magento cache:clean config
```